# I have some color problems with my threejs material

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I wanted to create a black and a white simple plane objects. I have 2 lights added to the scene (an ambient and a point):

```
...
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.1);
    this.light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.1 );
...
```

I also created then added my planes to scene:

```
...
    let plane1 = this.create('plane', this.white);
    let plane2 = this.create('plane', this.black);
    plane2.position.x = 3;

    this.scene.add(plane1);
    this.scene.add(plane2);
...
```

The result looks like this (ref picture):

[image]

This is so hard to tell which one is the white and which one is the black :( So I guess I did it wrong.

I think its because I use PhongMaterial on both. The reason is I use this type of material because  I want the lights be affected on them and I want to keep this shading they have. On the other hand I want to reduce this colorise effect that makes both of them black.

My materials (white and black):

```
white = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(<any>{
    alphaMap: null,
    alphaTest:0,
    aoMap:null,
    aoMapIntensity:1,
    blendDst:205,
    blendDstAlpha:null,
    blendEquation:100,
    blendEquationAlpha:null,
    blendSrc:204,
    blendSrcAlpha:null,
    blending:1,
    bumpMap:null,
    bumpScale:1,
    clipIntersection:false,
    clipShadows:false,
    clippingPlanes:null,
    color:{r: 0.8, g: 0.8, b: 0.8},
    colorWrite:true,
    combine:0,
    depthFunc:3,
    depthTest:true,
    depthWrite:true,
    displacementBias:0,
    displacementMap:null,
    displacementScale:1,
    dithering:false,
    emissive:{r: 0, g: 0, b: 0},
    emissiveIntensity:1,
    emissiveMap:null,
    envMap:null,
    flatShading:false,
    fog:true,
    lightMap:null,
    lightMapIntensity:1,
    lights:true,
    map:null,
    morphNormals:false,
    morphTargets:false,
    name:"Material",
    normalMap:null,
    normalScale:{x: 1, y: 1},
    opacity:1,
    overdraw:0,
    polygonOffset:false,
    polygonOffsetFactor:0,
    polygonOffsetUnits:0,
    precision:null,
    premultipliedAlpha:false,
    reflectivity:1,
    refractionRatio:0.97,
    shininess:50,
    side:2,
    skinning:false,
    specular: {r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5},
    specularMap:null,
    transparent:false,
    vertexColors:0,
    visible:true,
    wireframe:false,
    wireframeLinecap:"round",
    wireframeLinejoin:"round",
    wireframeLinewidth:1
  });

  black = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(<any>{
    alphaMap:null,
    alphaTest:0,
    aoMap:null,
    aoMapIntensity:1,
    blendDst:205,
    blendDstAlpha:null,
    blendEquation:100,
    blendEquationAlpha:null,
    blendSrc:204,
    blendSrcAlpha:null,
    blending:1,
    bumpMap:null,
    bumpScale:1,
    clipIntersection:false,
    clipShadows:false,
    clippingPlanes:null,
    color: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0},
    colorWrite:true,
    combine:0,
    depthFunc:3,
    depthTest:true,
    depthWrite:true,
    displacementBias:0,
    displacementMap:null,
    displacementScale:1,
    dithering:false,
    emissive: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0},
    emissiveIntensity:1,
    emissiveMap:null,
    envMap:null,
    flatShading:false,
    fog:true,
    lightMap:null,
    lightMapIntensity:1,
    lights:true,
    map:null,
    morphNormals:false,
    morphTargets:false,
    name:"Material",
    normalMap:null,
    normalScale: {x: 1, y: 1},
    opacity:1,
    overdraw:0,
    polygonOffset:false,
    polygonOffsetFactor:0,
    polygonOffsetUnits:0,
    precision:null,
    premultipliedAlpha:false,
    reflectivity:1,
    refractionRatio:0.98,
    shininess:50,
    side:2,
    skinning:false,
    specular: {r: 0.4, g: 0.4, b: 0.4},
    specularMap:null,
    transparent:false,
    vertexColors:0,
    visible:true,
    wireframe:false,
    wireframeLinecap:"round",
    wireframeLinejoin:"round",
    wireframeLinewidth:1
  });
```

Could someone experienced help me with this please? :)
Thanks your time in advance!

Comment: Intensity of ligths (0.1 + 0.1) is 0.2. Not sure if it's bright enough. Try to use 0.5 and 0.5 (1.0 in sum).

Comment: I changed them to 0.5 0.5 and now both of them is white

Comment: Have a look at the constructor of [`THREE.Color()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Color) and what types of parameter it takes.

Comment: It helped! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @prisoner849 Please consider writing an answer (with a bit more detail).

Answer (score -1):

PhongMaterial had not well defined objects in its constructor. Color property sould looks like this:

```
...
new THREE.COlor(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0)
...
```

instead of:

```
...
{r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}
...
```